# Write this division method in latex

Tags: equations

[image: Division method to find binary conversion from decimal]

How can I write this in LaTeX? As I'm using [codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) to convert equations written in latex to a png file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question is not very clear. What has codecogs to do with that? You could just use LaTeX with tikZ.

Comment: How am I suppose to do it... new to latex you know!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, calc}
\usepackage{old-arrows} 

\newcommand{\divstep}[1]%
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}2~\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{\widthof{9999}}}#1 \tabularnewline \hline\end{tabular}}% 

\begin{document}

\sffamily%
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newcounter{rowctr}\setcounter{rowctr}{0}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\hspace*{\dimexpr(\therowctr pt)*3}\stepcounter{rowctr}}c>{\rule[0.6ex]{0.8cm}{0.6pt}~}ll}
\divstep{4215} &1 & $\longleftarrow$ LSB\\
 \divstep{2107} &1 \\
 \divstep{1053} &1 \\
 \divstep{526} &0 \\
 \divstep{263} &1 \\
 \divstep{131} &1 \\
 \divstep{65} & 1 \\
 \divstep{32} & 0 \\
 \divstep{16} & 0 \\
 \divstep{8} & 0 \\
 \divstep{4} & 0 \\
 \divstep{2} & 0 \\
 \divstep{1} & 1 & $\longleftarrow$ MSB\\
~ 0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your concern this is not what I've been looking for... actually I will be compiling this in an online website named as 'codecogs' so they just don't accept document class and all

Comment: ??? Any LaTeX file must have a document class.What are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: check for this webpage 'codecogs' "write online latex editor in google" This will help me alot just checkout

Comment: This webpage will convert written equation into png file which is my desired output :)

Comment: I want ti convert a Latex code.  In question just press on codecogs!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible if it doesn't accept a wider set of LaTeX commands. But there are converters from pdf to png.

Comment: Actually those were less sized png files for my android application. Anyway! Thanks for your I appreciate your concern.