# How to write a long division equation upside down, to write quotients at bottom

Tags: longdivision

I want to write a long division equation upside down in Mathjax.

However, googling with similar keywards like 'longdiv upside down' did not give me a good solution.

A solution in [Write this division method in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411727/write-this-division-method-in-latex)
has vertical bar, but I want a bent bar.

I found another solution from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867785/way-to-show-long-division-symbol-in-mathjax) and modified `\longdiv` form to `)\underbar` form. This is the most similar to what I wanted, but both `\underline{sth}` and `\underline{\smash{sth}}` have a little gap at the edge. Their edge don't fit as good as `\longdiv`.

This is my question.
Can you tell me a grammar of this if it exist? Actually, I don't know whether this grammar exists.

---

The following is part of Mathjax code I made and the image of actual result. 
Sorry for the wrong way of numbers written, as it is a prototype. Please focus on the division symbol.

```
$$ 
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rll}

   4 \underline{\smash{)500\phantom{0}}} && \hbox{($4 \times 1 = 4$)} \\[-3pt]
      10\phantom{00} && \hbox{($5 - 4 = 1$)} \\[-3pt]
      \underline{) \phantom{0}8\phantom{00}} && \hbox{($4 \times 2 = 8$)} \\[-3pt]
      \phantom{00}20 \phantom{0} && \hbox{($10 - 8 = 2$)} \\[-3pt]
      \underline{)\phantom{0}20 \phantom{0}} && \hbox{($4 \times 5 = 20$)} \\[-3pt]
      \phantom{0}0 \phantom{0}
  \end{array}
$$
```

[image]

Comment: Since the tag has been added, but you code does not seem to relate: Did you try the [`longdivision` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longdivision)?

Comment: @JasperHabicht  Thanks for your suggestion. The package may have it and I will try it. I hope I can use it. Actually, I just make Latex code and send to colleage, who treats it on HTML webpage.

Comment: What does this mean? How is the LaTeX code being implemented in the HTML website? Do you need to use MathJax (which is not (La)TeX, but only uses a similar syntax)? Because then, you won't be able to use proper LaTeX packages, I fear.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yeah, that is why I memtioned in 1st line, tried not to use packages as possible, and made a symbol looking weird. It seems no basic option exists. Thanks for all your comments to help me.

Comment: The problem is that MathJax is *not* (La)TeX. It uses a similar syntax, but the way it parses this syntax and outputs things is quite different from (La)TeX (although the output might *look* very similar). Actually, due to that, MathJax questions are being considered off-topic on this site.